# Can't include JS file into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple file structure with HTML and JS files which looks like this:

```
templates/
 - index.html
 - menuselector.js
```

Here is an example of function that I want to import into HTML:

```
export function getTypeOfClient() {
    const select = document.getElementById('inputGroupSelect02');
    const value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value === '1') {
        document.getElementById('person').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('company').style.display = "none";
    } else if (value === '2') {
        document.getElementById('company').style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById('person').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('person').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('company').style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here is an example of HTML code that uses this function:

```
<select class="form-select" id="inputGroupSelect03" onchange="getTypeOfClient()">
     <option value="0" selected>Choose...</option>
     <option value="1">Person</option>
     <option value="2">Company</option>
</select>
```

When I write my code in `script` tag, everything works correctly, but I decided to export this code into JS file to make it more clean.

I import this in file like this - `<script type="text/javascript" src="menuselector.js"></script>`

And here is the problem. Every time in console I get 404 and not found this file. I was trying to import this in header, footer, body etc., but it doesn't work. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `src="./menuselector.js"`?

Comment: 404 means file not found. Check your file path with network inspector, make sure that it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use ES Modules as *inline event listeners* `onchange="getTypeOfClient()"` **as they don't get added to the global scope** (which is the whole point of modules).

Either explicitly assign it to the global scope using `window.getTypeOfClient = getTypeOfClient`, or remove the `export` keyword if you don't want ES modules.

That being said, using inline event listeners is very bad for a whole bunch of reasons; instead use Javascript to define or add the listener.

Comment: Well, you *can* use functions defined in modules as `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers (by assigning to properties on `window`), but you really, really shouldn't use that style of event handler in the first place. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Ofc you can always do that (and I've even added it as an option to my answer), but that is so far off that it didn't even come to mind to suggest that.